# Using async pipe with ngFor

Tags: angular

Ultimate goal is to use nested ngFor's created dynamically.
I try to create a series of drop-down menus, each depending on the previous one. The exact number of drop-down menus is unknown and created dynamically. Example:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="dropDownForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="#nr of numberOfDropdowns">
      <label>{{nr.name}}</label>
      <select [ngFormControl]="dropDownForm.controls[i]">
          <option  *ngFor="#item of Dropdown[nr.id] | async" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The whole things fails at Dropdown[nr.id] which does not seem to work with async pipe.
I played around a bit:

```
{{myAsyncObject | async}} //works
{{myAsyncObject['prop1'] | async}} //fails silently
{{myAsyncObject['prop1']['prop2'] | async}} // EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop2' of undefined in [null]
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, managed to solve it myself. Simply create a custom pipe and pass the parameters in. In my case:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'customPipe'
})
export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(obj: any, args: Array<string>) {
        if(obj) {
            return obj[args[0]][args[1]];
        }
    }
}
```

Then import:

```
import {CustomPipe} from '../pipes/custompipe'
@Component({
    selector: 'mypage',
    templateUrl: '../templates/mytemplate.html',
    pipes: [CustomPipe],
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

and use:

```
*ngFor="#obj of myAsyncObject | async | customPipe:'prop1':'prop2'"
```

Answer (score 36):

Just want to add an alternative that worked for me (no extra pipe necessary):

```
*ngFor="#obj of (myAsyncObject | async)?.prop1?.prop2"
```

Comment: maybe I've missed it before, but what does the ? flag do? Seems like it would make it optional or something?

Comment: You can look up safe navigation operator in angular2.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator   The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a more fluent and convenient way to guard against nulls in property paths. The expression bails out when it hits the first null value. The display is blank, but the app keeps rolling without errors.