# Using *ngFor properly with the async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-directives, rxjs5

I am unable to access a property of an object provided by the async pipe if I build the access chain using *ngFor.

In the example below, suppose that `Parking` in the test line and the `?.filter` two lines beneath represent the same key on the same object. The test line will evaluate to true, but the checked property does not. Why? How do I access the propery when stamping these out with *ngFor?

(Additionally, how should I access `propName` on `compModel`? `{{(compModel | async)?.(filter.propName)}}` wouldn't work anyway.)

```
    <fieldset class="filter-category-title">
      <legend>{{filter.name}}</legend>
        <label *ngFor="let instance of filter.options">
          test: {{(compModel | async)?.Parking}}
          <input type="checkbox"
                 checked={{(compModel | async)?.(filter.propName)?.instance}}
                 (click)="amenityEmit({category: filter.propName, filter: instance, resetCategory: false})">
                 {{instance}}
        </label>
    </fieldset>
```

*this is **not** related to this question: [Problems using async pipe with ngFor in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747069/problems-using-async-pipe-with-ngfor-in-angular2)

Comment: @JordanFrankfurt. I agree with estus. What's the point of using such a convoluted syntax inside your template? Keeping the component class clean? If I were you, I'd unwrap the data from the observable and store it in a nice, convenient property (after testing its existence, etc.) for the template to display. Do your 3 months from now self a favor: easier code to read is better. :)

Comment: Asked with more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057483/using-observables-in-an-angular-2-template-with-ngfor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using observables in an Angular 2 template with \*ngFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057483/using-observables-in-an-angular-2-template-with-ngfor)