# Using observables in an Angular 2 template with *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives, rxjs5

I am unable to access a property of an object provided by the async pipe if I build the access chain using *ngFor.

In the example below, suppose that `Parking` in the test line and the `?.[filter.propName]` two lines beneath represent the same key on the same object. The test line will evaluate to true, but the checked property does not. Why? How do I access the propery when stamping these out with *ngFor?

For example, if `{{(compModel | async)?.Parking?.Garage}} === true` I would expect `{{(compModel | async)?.[filter.propName].instance}} === true` as well, but this isn't the case.

The syntax below doesn't work. I'm using it to demonstrate intended functionality.

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters | async">
...
<fieldset class="filter-category-title">
      <legend>{{filter.name}}</legend>
        <label *ngFor="let instance of filter.options">
          test: {{(compModel | async)?.Parking.instance}}
          <input type="checkbox"
                 checked={{(compModel | async)?.[filter.propName].instance}}
                 (click)="amenityEmit({category: filter.propName, filter: instance, resetCategory: false})">
                 {{instance}}
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The filter data I get from the server in the format below. I use this to build a comparison model, also below, which is how I manage the state of my search results page. (`[key: string]` is always a propName from a Filter).

```
export interface Filter {
  base: boolean,
  filter: string,
  propName: string,
  unionType: string,
  inputType: string,
  options: {
    options: string[],
    sectionTitle: string
  }[] | string[]
}
```

compModel interface:

```
export interface CompModel {
  [key: string]: {
    touched: boolean
    unionType: string,
    options: {
      options: string[],
      sectionTitle: string
    }[] | string[],
    updateSelf(x: CompModel, y: Action): void
  }
}
```

Comment: `thing.['key']` doesn't make sense, it's either `thing.key` or `thing['key']`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `key.x` is a variable that evaluates to a string. Requesting chained properties would be incorrect here when the `x` I need is not under `thing.key.x`, but under `thing.x`. Since I only have access to `x` via `key.x`, that's how I'm accessing it. Should I be doing it another way?

Comment: To clarify - you are currently doing `thing1.[thing2.key]` which isn't valid syntax anywhere. `thing1[thing2.key]` would work, but can't be used with `?`.

Comment: Gotcha. I knew the above was incorrect, just didn't know how to handle the initial null value from the observable. Thank you! Also, the MX Master mouse on your wishlist is phenomenal. I'm using mine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe-navigation operator `?.` does not work with `[]`. There is no `?[]` operator and also no `?.[]` or `.[]` operator, therefore this can't work.

You can try

```
{{(compModel | async) && (compModel | async)[filter.propName].instance}} === true
```

otherwise you'll need to move some code to the components class

for example

```
this.compModel = someService.getSomeObservable()
.filter(val => !!val)
```

to ensure there are no `null` values

Comment: The first bit solved my problem, thank you so much! For the record, the null value I needed to handle was the observable null value on page load, not null values I got through the async subscription.