# Angular2 - how to use the async pipe with non array result?

Tags: javascript, angular

In [*this*](https://plnkr.co/edit/7kDczUZAYYh75vMLE45Y?p=preview)  Plunker I have this template :

```
 <span *ngFor="let a of Articles">{{a}}</span>
```

This is the component class :

```
export class App
{
    Articles: number[];
    constructor()
    {
        this.getData();
    }
    simualteDb()
    {
        return new Promise((a, b) =>
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                a(
                {    // notice , an object ,not an array
                    data: [0, 1, 2]
                });
            }, 500)
        });
    }
    async getData()
    {
        this.Articles = (await this.simualteDb()).data;
    }
}
```

This does work and I do see `012` in the output. But I want to use the `async` pipe.

So I want my template to be :

```
 <span *ngFor="let a of Articles |async ">{{a}}</span>
```

But there is a problem.

`Articles` is not an array. It is an object with `data` prop which *is* the required array.

I can't do something like this :

```
   <span *ngFor="let a of Articles.data |async ">{{a}}</span>
```

I've created another [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lJHYEDT8u09YlJr84iEN?p=preview) which  returns only an array :

and It does work with `|async`.

**Question:**

Looking at my first code , How can I use the `async pipe` while still resolving an object and not an array ?

```
{data: [0, 1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving you the other option to use the async pipe (which you mentioned you wanted), means that you need to have an Observable to work with... service returns Observable:

```ts
getArticles() {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

And in the component assign the Observable:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.Articles = this.service.getArticles()
}
```

Then you can use the async pipe in your view like so:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let a of (Articles | async)?.data">{{a}}</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uiVeaJKAwsNGK9q8OSrj?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah I 've just seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35302622/859154) and it can be used with promises also  - [here is a demo plunker of mine with promise and async pipe](https://plnkr.co/edit/mK2tWJmmkm4qlZ7DWYq4?p=preview). so the "_you need to have an Observable_" part is incorrect  ;-)

Comment: @Royi I also tried it like you did but with `await` infront of the Promise as your plunker included it. I was trying to figure out what was wrong :D

Comment: Yes, it can be used with promises but AsyncPipe can't consume array or object. Only `Observable, Promise or EventEmitter` The next wont work `{data: [0, 1, 2]} | async` and `[0,1,2] | async`

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the clarification.