# Angular2 Observable isn't triggered by async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Consider this simple snippet of angular2/rxjs/typescript

```
  public rooms: Observable<Room[]>;      

  constructor ( ... ) {

    this.rooms = this.inspectShipSubject
      .do(() => console.log('foo'))
      .switchMap(ship => this.roomByShipService.getRoomsByShip(ship));

    //this.rooms.subscribe(); // <-- [1]
  }
```

Here's the template:

```
<some-component *ngFor="let room of rooms | async" [room]="room"></some-component>
```

It doesn't work ('foo' is not printed and no data shows) unless I uncomment the line indicated `[1]`. Why doesn't the template trigger the observable to execute automatically?

Is there a better way than to use a blank subscribe?

Comment: Can you try putting the expresion `(rooms | async)` into parenthesis?

Comment: Try moving the this.rooms initialization from your constructor to ngOnInit()

Comment: @martin Thanks, I tried that and it didn't make a difference. I'm not sure which is correct because many examples used both styles.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302622/1919228. The async pipe already adds a subscription

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru Thanks, I tried this with the above suggestion and didn't see a difference.

Comment: @PabloLozano I think that answer is very old, potentially invalid, because I tried it and the syntax is no longer allowed (for example, their `*ngFor` is missing `let`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'm not sure why, but the trick is to use `BehaviourSubject` instead of `Subject` on `this.inspectShipSubject`.

This works nicely and is triggered properly by the template.

```
  public rooms$: Observable<Room[]>;

  private inspectShipSubject: BehaviorSubject<Ship> = new BehaviorSubject<Ship>(null);

  constructor(
    ...
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rooms$ = this.inspectShipSubject.switchMap(ship => this.roomByShipService.getRoomsByShip(ship));
  }

  @Input()
  set ship(ship: Ship) {
    this.inspectShipSubject.next(ship);
  }

  get ship(): Ship {
    return this.inspectShipSubject.getValue();
  }
```

And the template:

```
<some-component *ngFor="let room of (rooms | async)" [room]="room"></some-component>
```

Comment: Oh, you were using a Subject for `inspectShipSubject`...should have realized that from the name :). To better understand the difference to a BehaviorSubject, have a look at [this article](https://netbasal.com/rxjs-subjects-for-human-beings-7807818d4e4d)

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru, so why did it make the difference here?

Comment: Please do explain :)

Comment: If it's a regular Subject, and you emit a value *before* you subscribe to it, the subscriber won't get that value. *It will only get values emitted after it subscribed.* So in your case it probably wouldn't be triggered until the first change happens. Subjects only relay values as they are emitted. Whereas, a BehaviorSubject additionally stores a 'current' value, and will send that value to new subscribers. You must provide an initial 'current' value when you construct the BehaviorSubject (often null), as you did. ReplaySubject is another option you could look into. But I'm out of space

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good solution (or just a workaround), but you could store every event in an array and then loop the array:

```
this.rooms=[];
this.roomsObservable = this.inspectShipSubject
      .switchMap(ship => this.roomByShipService.getRoomsByShip(ship))
      .observe(next =>this.rooms.push(next));
```

Edit: I have just realized that I'm not sure if you want to show a list of rooms or just the latest received room. In case you just need the latest one, then I think you don't need a ngFor directive.